How much propulsion could solar weather induced variations in Earth's magnetic field provide?
The Bifrost Drive is so named because it taps into a source of energy that drives the aurora borealis.  It works as follows:

A craft is placed into the Earth's magnetotail near the L2 point.  (I think the L2 point is at 1.5 Gm and the magnetotail is somewhat over 6 Gm on average)
It uses thrusters to begin a gentle rotation, and lays out line of a potentially superconducting material.
When a suitable coronal mass ejection is detected at the sun, the craft begins refrigerating its superconductor to bring it down well below the critical temperature.
When the CME hits, the Earth's magnetotail gets blown away.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLLq6plMjU0 .
Because magnetic field lines can't cross a superconductor, the craft must get blown away with it... I think.  In other words, a current is induced in the superconductor strong enough to interact with a local magnetic gradient, and the superconducting wire connected to the craft in some cleverly distributed way that reduces the tension developed.

How much propulsion can the Bifrost Drive provide?  (use any means of measurement you think are appropriate ... I'm not sure a specific impulse figure is the best way to describe it)

My overwhelming impulse is to say "not much", because despite the scale of Earth's magnetic field, power density is extremely low.  But I cannot provide figures for how little would be involved.   I would place money on "so little that the mass budget for your superconductor and cooling apparatus is going to be a losing proposition particularly if you need thruster mass to deploy it".

Assuming you could pin your ship to the magnetotail, which is the mother of all assumptions given the low field strength:
The tail is going to be blown away at about the speed of the solar winds; CMEs tend to accelerate or decelerate to match the solar winds. So the tail is going to be blown away at 250-750km/s, to work out the Delta-v this imparts to the ship we need to know the ship mass and how long those pinned field lines last without the Earth's internal dynamo but that's the top speed you could ever possibly expect to reach.
Acceleration is not going to be smooth with this set up though, it's going to be a single, effectively instantaneous, jerk from relatively stationary to whatever the top speed is. Unless the total Delta-v is very low indeed, which I think it could be, the G forces are going to be pretty lethal. I'd say this ship will either not move because the field strength isn't there for pinning to be effective in the first place or it's going to shatter as it goes through a near infinite acceleration phase, with minor keys in a tiny, and thus survivable, acceleration and in accidentally catching the internal magnetic field of the CME and getting yanked off into the universe by it with, again, either an obscene or negligible acceleration.
